# Properly rendering HTML Content wrapped in a JSON Object fetched from REST API in a Native App

Tags: android, html

I Have Built a REST API (App server) for a news android application, My app server fetch articles from a wordpress blog and provides that data via various endpoints in JSON format, The android application is built and things works fine except a small problem mentioned below.

> **The Problem**

One of the endpoints of the app server is Posts, Which Gives out data of the post requested. [Click Here To See The Endpoint Live](http://13.233.182.187/api_v1/post?post_id=14898)

My Android developer is not able to render content part of the object fetched from above endpoint and display few HTML things like Embedded Twitter Tweets, Images, Embedded Youtube Videos, Facebook Posts in the Android App. While the data display well in website and or when put in an HTML file.

Not Expecting a Code In Reply just suggestion how to show such HTML things in an android app ?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the html content as an html file at run time, then load the saved file into a webview.

Comment: is this a good idea on a production app ? there is no other way by using some parser or something ?